# Why I can't save on db ? PHP MYSqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have tried to save on db which is relational tables 1- dealer table(bayi) and 2- dealer offer (bTeklif). Even all the areas are the correct key not saving on db ı have struggled about 3 days and couldn't find. What's the problem ?

my form data =>

[image: from console]

tables relation =>

[image: from PhpMyAdmin]

HERE IS MY FORM AREA

```
  <form method="post" action="<?=BAYI_TEKLIF?>">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-header-title">
              Bayi Teklif bilgileri
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-floating form-group">

    <select class="form-control" id="form_bid" name="form_bid">
  <option value="-1">Lütfen müşteri seçin</option>
  <?php
  $bteklifler = $db->query("SELECT bId, bAdi
      FROM bayi AS b
      LEFT JOIN bTeklif  AS t ON b.bId = t.bayi_id");
      
  if ($bteklifler->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($bTeklif = $bteklifler->fetch_object()) {
    
      ?>
      <option value="<?= $bTeklif->bId ?>"> <?=($bTeklif->bId == $bTeklif->bayi_id ? 'selected' : '' )?>><?= $bTeklif->bAdi ?> MAKRO</option>
      <?php
    }
  } else {
    // müşteri yok
  }
  ?>
</select>
                  </div>
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="form-floating form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_btek" name="form_btek" placeholder="Teklif Adı" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off">
              <label for="form_btek">Teklife bir isim verin</label>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="form_bdetay">Teklif ile ilgili detay verebilirsiniz</label>
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="form_bdetay" name="form_bdetay" placeholder="Teklif detayları" rows="5"></textarea>
              <div class="form-text">Mümkün olduğunca detay verebilirsiniz.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating form-group">
              <input type="number"   class="form-control" id="form_bfiyat" name="form_bfiyat" placeholder="Teklif Fiyat">
              <label for="form_bfiyat">Teklif Fiyat</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="form_bbasl" class="form-label fw-bold">Teklif başlangıç tarihi</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_bbasl" name="form_bbasl" value="<?=datetr('Y-m-d H:i:s', '+7 days')?>">
                    <div class="form-text">Teklif yukarıdaki tarihten itibaren geçerli olacaktır.</div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="form_bbits" class="form-label fw-bold">Teklifin geçerlilik tarihi</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_bbits" name="form_bbits" value="<?=datetr('Y-m-d H:i:s', '+7 days')?>">
                    <div class="form-text">Teklifin son geçerlilik tarihi.</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer d-flex">
                <button class="btn btn-primary ms-auto text-nowrap" type="submit" id="" name="bteklif" value="bayi-teklif">Teklifi Kaydet</button>
                </div>
    </form>
```

HERE IS MY BINDING AREA

````
<?php
     $bteklifler = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bTeklif");
     $bteklif = $bteklifler->fetch_object();
    
     if(isset($_GET['bteklif']) ) {
      $bteklif = $_GET['btek'];
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['bteklif']) ) {
      $bteklif  = $_POST['bteklif'];
    }
      
     if ($bteklif == 'bayi-teklif') {
          $form_bid = temizle_stdString($_POST['form_bid']);
          $form_btek = temizle_stdString($_POST['form_btek']);
          $form_bdetay = temizle_stdString($_POST['form_bdetay']);
          $form_bfiyat = temizle_stdString($_POST['form_bfiyat']);
          $form_bbasl = temizle_stdString($_POST['form_bbasl']);
          $form_bbits = temizle_stdString($_POST['form_bbits']);

        //sss olmasının sebebi 3 adet string olması
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bTeklif (bayi_id, btAdi, btDetay, btFiyat, btBasl, bBits) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ississ", $form_bid, $form_btek, $form_bdetay, $form_bfiyat, $form_bbasl, $form_bbits);
        

       
          $stmt->execute();
          
           $stmt->close();
           $db->close();


        
    }```


I have tried making tables from sql code (code first) , change the all types to string, 
change binding names, cut off the relational area (primary key )
````

Comment: This information is too vague for us to help you easily. What specific problem/error do you see? And what debugging have you done? Your INSERT command may not run if the `if ($bteklif == 'bayi-teklif') {` condition is not met. Have you tested this? Does the code enter the `if` block? If it doesn't, you should debug your POST request to see what value was submitted instead, and why. If it does, then turn on PDO error reporting to find out why the SQL query fails.

Comment: First of all, it's not PDO. You are using mysqli. Regarding your question, we can never tell. You have to ask *your* and your MySQL, what is the problem. Follow the recommendation from the answer linked at the top

Comment: First of all thanks for return and ı haven't  debug but as you can see from form area it must be enter if statement which is  **bayi-teklif **. And also from payload area bindings are ok . What should ı do  ?

Comment: Why not start debugging? Either use XDebug to properly step through the execution of your code, or use var_dump to check which parts are actually executed

Comment: I guess ı need to debug , because of why is ı haven't debug before and ı have not much php information

Comment: Well not you have exact instruction on how to debug this issue. Please feel free to ask any questions regarding the process.

Comment: I have tried to debug PHP Debug and Xdebug but ı can't reach any request. My project working on server is it related?